# How do I update R CRAN packages when updating from Debian buster to bullseye?

Tags: debian, repository, r

I need to update a server, which has the R statistics system installed from the [CRAN repo](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian/), from Debian 10 (buster) to Debian 11 (bullseye).

The "repo line" for the `buster` CRAN repo is stored in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/buster-cran40.list`.

To use the `bullseye` CRAN repo, do I just need to replace this file and its contents with the corresponding version for `bullseye-cran40`, and then (after editing the Debian repo settings in the main `sources.list` file) run `apt update`, etc, or is it a more complicated process than this (eg, might I perhaps have to uninstall the existing CRAN packages first?).

Answer (score 1):

Keeping the Third party repository enable during the distribution upgrade is possible under Ubuntu Bionic and higher through [the Ubuntu's release upgrades](https://wiki.debian.org/AutomatedUpgrade#Ubuntu.27s_release_upgrades), see [Keep PPAs Enabled when Upgrading Releases](https://support.system76.com/articles/ppa-third-party/), but on Debian you need to make changes manually.